# Palo Alto Template Revert error

Tags: palo-alto

I am a network engineer and we have recently swapped out some Palo Alto firewalls for newer models. The old firewalls were managed in Panorama and I recently tried to integrate these new firewalls to Panorama. I want both the Device Groups (Policies and Objects tabs) and Templates (Network and Device tabs) to be managed by Panorama apart from the Device > High Availability and Setup sections which I want managed locally.

It went smoothly until I reached step 8 in the below Palo Alto document.

https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/panorama/9-0/panorama-admin/manage-firewalls/transition-a-firewall-to-panorama-management/migrate-a-firewall-ha-pair-to-panorama-management.html

I decided against selecting 'Force Template Values' when I pushed the config to the firewalls because Device > High Availability and Setup should be managed locally, not by Panorama. I was hoping that if I skip selecting 'Force Template Values' I can simply click on everything apart from High Availability and Setup and click Revert locally on the firewall to have this managed in Panorama. When I started doing this however on the Interfaces I got the below error
[image]

I have tried to revert VR-1 then do a commit then revert the interfaces but I am still getting the same error above. I don't want to 'Force Template Values' on Panorama as the High Availability and Setup on teh loca firewalls will be deleted. Any idea how I can add the Teamplate (Network and Device tabs) to be managed by Panorama without adding High Availability and Setup too?

Panorama is version 9.1.8 and model M-100

Firewalls are version 9.1.8 and model PA-5250 in Active Passive setup.

Many thanks in advance!